# What is the meaning of sentence "homomorphism of G onto G"?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Actually I encountered a question wherein I was asked to find whether There exist any Homomorphism of G onto G'. I am confused whether it means homomorphism + onto, or just Homomorphism?

Comment: This is pretty vague, but generally "onto" means surjective (just as "into" means injective).

Comment: @lulu "onto" means surjective but I have never seen anybody writing "into" for injective. Certainly not in Analysis books.

Comment: @geetha290krm  Really?  I thought it was standard, it certainly used to be (though vocabulary changes over time, of course). [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/onto-vs-into.399682/#:~:text=%22Onto%22%20means%20that%20the%20codomain,to%20use%20%22injective%22%20instead.) is one reference, [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/set-theory-onto-and-into-their-relation-to-spoken-language-definitions) another.

Comment: @geetha290krm  I can see why it might have fallen out of fashion, as there is a temptation to call *any* map from $A\to B$, a map into $B$.  Still, parallel construction and all...if surjective maps get their own shorthand term, it seems only fair to give one to injective maps.

Comment: @geetha290krm  I note that both the references I provided include suggestions that "into=injective" is at least uncertain usage, so it does seem likely that the term has declined in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, to get the true answer, you will have to read the mind of whichever author wrote it (unless they have made it explicitly clear earlier in the text what they mean when they say something like this). That being said, it is a relatively safe guess that they mean "an onto homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$" (or equivalently "a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$") when they say "a homomorphism from $G$ onto $G'$".

Further information can likely be gleaned from the immediate surrounding context of wherever you found this phrase. In this case, where it seems to be an exercise, if it turns out that there *is* an onto homomorphism, then you're most likely asked to show all of that, rather than just that there is a homomorphism. Of course, that's difficult for you to judge as the one who is trying to solve the exercises.

Answer (score 0):

The key word "Onto" specifically demands surjectivity as a requirement.  The specific word for a morphism with equal domain and codomain is epimorphism. But, the way you wrote it, homomorphism + onto, is equivalent.